# c++ call a member in class by string

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I have a class C which should have some members. But this members should be automaticly added to a map so I can access them easy with a string.

So the idea is to have a struct called parameter and the struct save it to a map or something else...

But I'm not shure how I should use the map. My idea was to create a map with a pointer to member value. But how to initialize this member in the struct constructor?

```
  template <typename C>
  struct parameter {
    typedef int (parameter::*mfp)(int);
    static std::map<std::string, mfp> registered_parameter;

    parameter(std::string name) {
      // todo...
    }

    // parameter overloading code and something other here ... 
  };
```

The template is for have a static map each class. C1 and C2 Class should be have different maps.

```
C1 could be look: 
class C1: public C {
  parameter<C1> x("x");
  parameter<C1> y("y");
}
```

And if I'm doing something like:

```
C1 c1_1;
C1 c1_2;

// should be different x
c1_1.x = 2
c1_2.x = 3
```

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: `mfp` is a pointer to member function, not a pointer to member value. `parameter` doesn't have any members that `mfp` could point to. `c1_1.x` is a `parameter` but it doesn't have an `operator =(int)` to make `c1_1.x = 2;` compile. Please try to flesh out the question and show an example of the code you want to write assuming that `parameter` does what you want. Currently your example doesn't do anything.

Comment: class C have the parameter struct in. I though I dont need to write this like the overloading too because it obviously that there have to be operator overloading. @nwp my point is, I dont know how I can add the "this" into the map so I can easily get it by a string

Comment: The `this` you are referring to is a `C*` right? You can just put that into the `map`. Maybe make a `map<string, pair<C*, mfp>>` or something like that.

Comment: But then my map would be bigger and bigger for every new instance of a C object

Comment: Either you put every `this` into the `map` and the `map` grows by 1 element per `C` object or you don't have the `this` in the `map`. There is no way to store arbitrary data in 0 bytes. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: the main thing is. I want to have access to member variables in my class by call them through a string.

Comment: @R3Tech member variables can not be "called" in general. Unless those member variables are function pointers, or objects of type that overload `operator()`.

Comment: yeah and for that my idea was to capsule them into a struct...

Comment: Please make an example where you use the string. None of your examples have anything to do with using a member variable/function through a string.

Comment: @R3Tech if the struct is supposed to be the wrapper for the variable, shouldn't the map point to an instance of the struct, rather than a member function of the struct?

Comment: Some values comes through a file and the handler should be able to do something like `c.getParam(VALUE_IN_FILE)` or set the param. @user2079303 the map should be unique for every instance of c and not for every class

Comment: @R3Tech If you need the map to be different for each instance, then you need each instance to have a different map. Therefore it cannot be a static member.

Answer (score 0):

> dont know how I can add the "this" into the map

And you can't know it, because `this` can not be added into the map. The map contains pointers to member functions of `parameter`. `this` is not a member function of `parameter`, but a pointer to a `parameter`.

Since it appears to be your intention to have a mapping from a string to the parameter that is a member of C, it seems that the mapped type should be a member pointer of C, of type parameter. Furthermore, I recommend making the map const. After all, the class doesn't change at run time, so it is best to prevent modification of the map since it is almost certainly a mistake.

```
static const std::map<std::string, parameter C::*> registered_parameter;
```

> But how to initialize this member in the struct constructor?

You don't initialize static members in constructors. There is only one instance of a static member, which should be initialized before even the first object is constructed. Of course, you will need to specialize the initialization for each class.

A static member can be specialized like this:

```
template<>
const std::map<std::string, parameter<C1> C1::*>
parameter<C1>::registered_parameter = {
    {"x", &C1::x},
    {"y", &C1::y},
};
```

However, note that the parameter members have to be public for this to work.